# nth root - sequence convergence proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I apologise for the ambiguous title. I found selecting an appropriate title difficult using only text.

If $0\leq \alpha \leq \beta$, define $\{a_n\}$ by $a_n = \sqrt[n]{\alpha ^n+\beta ^n}$. Prove that $\{a_n\}$ converges to $\beta$.

I'm quite lost on this one; any help getting started is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

$$\beta = \sqrt[n]{\beta ^n} \leq \sqrt[n]{\alpha ^n+\beta ^n}\leq \sqrt[n]{\beta^n+\beta ^n} = \sqrt[n]{2\beta ^n}= \sqrt[n]{2}\cdot \beta\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \beta$$

Using the squeeze theorem, we get $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\alpha ^n+\beta ^n} = \beta$

Answer (score 3):

write it as $$\beta\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)^n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}
\ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\alpha^n+\beta^n} &=\lim_{n \to \infty} \beta \sqrt[n]{\left( \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \right) ^n +1} \\
&=\bigg( \lim_{n \to \infty} \beta \bigg) \cdot \bigg( \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{ \frac{\alpha^n}{\beta^n} +1} \bigg)\\
\end{array}$

Now apply the fact that $0 \leq \alpha \leq \beta$. What happens to $\frac{\alpha^n}{\beta^n}$ as $n\to\infty$?